# javascript switch with multiple variables in case

Tags: javascript

This feels like a silly question but I can't get it to work:

I am building an event handler that I want to trigger two different outcomes if the user presses "enter" or "shift Enter"

I have this code

```
         switch(e){
            case (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey):
                console.log("Enter")
                break;
            case (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey):
                console.log("Enter&Shift")
                break;
            default:
                console.log(`Sorry, we are out of it.`);
        }
```

but something is not working because it always go to default...despite the fact that e.keyValue is actually 13 and e.shiftKey is true...so I am passing the event correctly.

It's the switch that is wrongly built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `switch` statement for this, but regular `if` and `else` statements.

```js
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("Enter");
} else if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("Enter&Shift");
} else {
    console.log(`Sorry, we are out of it.`);
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly common duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks.

I understand how to do this with if...but to be honest that's not what I asked. I was trying to do so using switch and my question was on why was I failing...

Comment: @giaggi Well you would need to use `switch(true)`, which is not a good use of `switch`.

Comment: @giaggi - Which reading the answers to the linked previous versions of this question would tell you.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's all clear! Appreaciate the help!